# Plotting a 2D vector with separate component arrays

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, vector, components, velocity

I feel like this is a pretty basic question but I can't see to get my head around it. I have a velocity vector V with two components in x and in y that both depend on time. v_x(t) = sin(a*t) and v_y(t) = exp(b*t).

I have created an array for t ranging from 0 to 100 with the function np.arange(0,100,1). I want to plot with matplotlib the resulting vector and its evolution with respect to t. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way that you might try is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0,100,1)
a = 0.1
b = 0.05

vel = np.array([np.sin(a*t), np.exp(b*t)],float)

plt.plot(vel[0,:],vel[1,:])
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.show()
```

This gave me the plot

[image: velocity vector evolution over time]

The line `vel = np.array([np.sin(a*t), np.exp(b*t)],float)` basically does all the magic. `np.sin(a*t)` makes a new array using each value in `t` to calculate each element (and `np.exp()` works similarly).

It would also be possible (and fun) to make an animation of the evolution of the vector.